# what is the difference between "l'argent" and "la monnaie" ?

Tags: vocabulaire

What is the difference between "l'argent" and "la monnaie" ? 
Are both used to reference to money ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Argent` (which literally means "silver") is used to mean "money" in all cases.

`Monnaie` has several different usages:

- "coins", especially `petite monnaie`
- "change", as in "the money given back to you after you pay with more than the exact amount", which can perfectly well include bills
- "any small amount of cash", as in `T'as de la monnaie ?` (an English-speaker could well say "Do you have some change?"). I often understand this as stemming from "do you have some small coins so that I can make up the exact amount on what I have to pay so that I don't have to break out a large bill or cheque or card?", which is more polite than "I don't have any money, can you help me out?". I have absolutely no research for this interpretation!
- "currency", as in `La monnaie américaine est le dollar`, or `La monnaie britannique connaît des problèmes à cause du Brexit`.

You also have the word `pièce / pièces` (short for `pièces de monnaie`), which (in context) always means "coin / coins" (cf. "thirty pieces of silver", "pieces of eight"), as opposed to `billets` (short for `billets de banque`), which is paper money (cf. "bill", "banknote").

Answer (score 2):

"L'argent" can be related to everything about money like banknotes or coins.
"monnaie" is usually use to speak about coins only.

Comment: Welcome to FrenchSE. You should add some sources to validate your answer. Don't forget to make a [tour] !